# Using Cucumber / Watir unable to locate element, using {:xpath=>"//*[@id='use-0']", :tag_name=>"a"}

Tags: cucumber, watir

Using Cucumber / Watir: unable to locate element.

Description: I am trying to click on Cash Back.

When I use the following  with irb : it works

```
browser.link(:id => 'use-0').click
Error: Watir: unable to locate element, using {:xpath=>"//*[@id='use-0']", :tag_name=>"a"}
```

I have tried to wait until Present . Stuck on this for days . Please help.
a.

HTML: `<a id="use-0" class="ng-binding" href="/ur2/cash_back"></a>`

b.

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'watir-webdriver'
browser = Watir::Browser.new
browser.goto xxxxxxx
```

c.

```
def cash=(cash)
  @browser.a(:xpath, "//*[@id='use-0']").click
End
```

d.

```
Given(/^I can click Get Cash Back from the sub-menu options.$/) do
  @browser.a(:xpath, "//*[@id='use-0']").click
end
```

Comment: Welcome on Stack Overflow! Please format your question in a proper way , you will get more chance to get a response. It's important to visually separate your code from other sentences (you can indent it or click on the {} icon)

Comment: I'm a bit confused.  Does `browser.a(:id => "use-0").click` work?  And you'll want to change `End` to `end`.

Comment: Browser works only when I execute the following code thru irb :

Comment: @browser works only thru irb. When I try the same with cucumber as executed thru the command line I get the error unable to find elelemt

Comment: tries xpath via cucumber and that did not work

Comment: Could it be in a frame, then?  Can you provide more complete HTML?

Comment: Thanks for your help. Here is the complete html....

Comment: <a id="use-0" class="ng-binding" href="/ur2/cash_back">

    <span class="icon-cash-back" ng-class="'icon-cash-back'"></span>

     Get Cash Back

</a>

Comment: Heh.  I was thinking even more complete (i.e. up to the parent container, which may indicate a frame).  This [blog post](http://jkotests.wordpress.com/unable-to-locate-element/) might help also.

Comment: The app did not have unique ID's of any kind so I made a request fo ID's to be provided, hence use-0 = Cash back.

Comment: <a class="b2s-dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="">

    Use Points 

    <span class="icon-caret-down"></span>

</a>
<ul class="b2s-dropdown-menu ng-hide" ng-show="openMenu == 'UsePoints'">

    <!--

     ngRepeat: link in header.usePointsMenu 

    -->
    <li class="ng-scope" ng-repeat="link in header.usePointsMenu">
        <a id="use-0" class="ng-binding" href="/ur2/cash_back">
            <span class="icon-cash-back" ng-class="'icon-cash-back'"></span>

             Get Cash Back

        </a>
    </li>
    <!--

Comment: That's about as much as the comment box will allow. By the way the elements in question exist as part of a toolbar. So they are items. I am reviewing the blog post you provided. Thanks

Comment: Are you sure your Cucumber script is doing exactly the same steps as you are doing in irb? The html suggests this might be in a dropdown? If so perhaps the dropdown is not being triggered to populate?

Comment: Same code  different result. this is the meat  of the irb

Comment: #Enter all the required fields
x=0
for x in 0..2 do
browser.send_keys :tab
end
browser.send_keys :space
x=0

sleep 3

for x in 0..7 do
browser.send_keys :tab
end

browser.send_keys :enter
sleep 3
browser.link(:id => 'use-0').click

Comment: the sendkeys trigger the dropdown to open. I have tried multiple wait until XXX but the Cash back is never clicked  after 30 seconds and times out when I add more time to the wait. I am stumped ...

Comment: feature file = Feature: Chase Login Page
  As an Automation Test
  I want to Login to the Chase Application

  Scenario: Chase Login
  Given I am on the Login Page
  When I enter 'Pending' in the Name ID field
  Then I enter 'Pending' in the Account in context field
  Then I click the landing Page submit button


  Scenario: Chase_UR2.0_Cash_Back_JPUR-113_001

    Given I can click Get Cash Back from the sub-menu options.

Comment: step def = Feature: Chase Login Page
  As an Automation Test
  I want to Login to the Chase Application

  Scenario: Chase Login
  Given I am on the Login Page
  When I enter 'Pending' in the Name ID field
  Then I enter 'Pending' in the Account in context field
  Then I click the landing Page submit button


  Scenario: Chase_UR2.0_Cash_Back_JPUR-113_001

    Given I can click Get Cash Back from the sub-menu options.

Comment: Putting code in comments is not really readable. You can edit the question to add the additional code/information.